# Scipy curve_fit RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a function with two independent variables `a` and `k` to an exponential curve using scipy's `curve_fit`. I have defined the function and tried to calculate it like this:

```
print(np.min(x_data))
1
print(np.max(x_data))
44098
print(x_data.dtype)
int64
print(np.size(x_data))
44098

print(np.min(y_data))
-0.44383433
print(np.max(y_data))
1.0
print(y_data.dtype)
float32
print(np.size(y_data))
44098

def exponential(x, a, k, b):
    return a*np.exp(x*k) + b

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(exponential, x_data, y_data, p0=[1, -0.5, 1])
print(popt)
[ 1.28765636e+00 -3.27620187e-04 -8.91012481e-02]
/software/repo/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  
/software/repo/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
```

This results in a warning as my data is too large. Changing the datatype all the way up to `complex256` is still not big enough. So I tried updating the bounds; making large enough bounds overcomes the error, but I do not know if I am doing this correctly as the fitted variables become dependent on the bounds I choose.

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(exponential, x_data, y_data, bounds=([1, -1e100, 1], [1e100, 1, 1e100]))
print(popt)
[ 5.e+99 -5.e+99  5.e+99]
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(exponential, x_data, y_data, bounds=([1, -1e1000, 1], [1e1000, 1, 1e1000]))
print(popt)
[ 1.00448191 -5.15058477  1.        ]
```

What is going on here? What do I need to do to properly fit this function? I also tinkered with the `Decimal` module, without success. Thank you!

Comment: Tell us about the data - array size and dtype, but more importantly the range of values (max and min).  Have you tested `exponential(x_data, 1, -.5, 1)`.  Or with the `popt` values.  All curve_fit is doing is comparing `y_data` with the function run with `x_data`.  You can do those sample calculations without going through `curve_fit`.

Comment: `np.exp(-.5*(-1e4))` produces the overflow warning along with a `inf` value.  This isn't an underflow or precision issue.

Comment: good point @hpaulj; I added min and max values, and the dtype of the data

Comment: how many data points do you have? what does the plot look like? does it qualitatively look like an exponential? Besides that `np.exp(kx)` is going to return `inf` with such large values of `x` or `0` if `k < 0`

Comment: yes @DrBwts, it does look like an exponential (I can show figures if needed). There are 44k data points

Comment: Do you know the value of `b`? If you need to adjust two parameters, then your `p0` must have two elements. You need to redefine the function to `exponential(x, a, k)` and assign the value of `b`.

Comment: Fit to the log of the y values; that removes the exponential, and makes the fit much more feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp(a)` with float64 values (which is the default for numpy) overflows from values of ~1.e308 to `numpy.Inf` for `a` > 709.75 or so.

For your case, that means that your `k` value must satisfy
`x*k <=709`.  Since your `x` values go up to values of `44098`, the maximum value allowed for `k` should be about 0.016.   If you expect `k` to always be negative, you could give a maximum value of 0.

FWIW, `exp` will underflow for values of `a` below -709.75.  In that case, the result goes to 0 which does not cause an exception but might make fitting difficult.

You could cast your problem to use `float128` which will raise the threshold for overflowing, but I believe this will not work with most curve-fitting routines -- they work with float64 values, and it is sort of doubtful that this is really needed in your case.